# I am trying to get a populate grid to display a dynamic date from a $VAR on a web page

Tags: fitnesse, appian

In Fitnesse for Appian to Chrome browse

Code snip it
!***> FitNesse Configurations

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define DATE ${!today (yyyy-MM-dd)}
!define TEXT ${"Hello World"}

*!
!*** Click on

!define DATE ${!today (yyyy-MM-dd)}
!define TEXT ${"Hello World"}

!| script|
|populate grid|[2]|column|Date:1|row|[1]|with|{$DATE}|
|populate field|Comments|with|{$DATE}|
|populate field|Comments|with|{$TEXT}|

***!
```

I also tried to send it to a text field

The !define response correctly.
!define DATE ${2023-06-05}
!define TEXT ${"Hello World"}

but the web page does not.
populate field  Comments    with    {$DATE}
populate field  Comments    with    {$TEXT}

I know I probably just have the syntax wrong, but I am out of ideas.
Any suggestions or help would be great

Expected results
populate grid   [2] column  Date:1  row [1] with    2023-06-05
populate field  Comments    with    2023-06-05
populate field  Comments    with    Hello World